# ZXing is not detecting QR Code on iOS device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am creating a program to read QR codes in Xamarin. I followed the steps from this link.

> https://siddheshshelke.wordpress.com/2020/08/07/qrcode-generator-and-scanner-for-xamarin-forms-using-zxing-nuget/

it is working perfectly on Andriod but not on iOS.
I tried with different versions of

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms
```

and beta versions as well nothing gave me the result.

here is my code.

```
var scanPageOptions = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
        {
            AutoRotate = false,
            TryInverted = true,
            TryHarder = true,
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }
        };
        var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(scanPageOptions);
            scanPage.IsAnalyzing = true;
            scanPage.IsScanning = true;
            scanPage.IsTorchOn = true;

            scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
            {
                scanPage.IsScanning = false;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await Navigation.PopAsync();
                        await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                    DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", "No Barcode Found", "OK");
                }
                
            };

            await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
```

I tried another way as well that is.

```
MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.TopText = "Hold the camera up to the barcode\nAbout 6 inches away";
        scanner.BottomText = "Wait for the barcode to automatically scan!";
        scanner.AutoFocus();
        //This will start scanning

        var scanPageOptions = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
        {
            AutoRotate = false,
            TryInverted = true,
            TryHarder = true,
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }
        };

        ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan(scanPageOptions);
        var msg = "No Barcode!";
        if (result != null)
        {
            msg = "Barcode: " + result.Text + " (" + result.BarcodeFormat + ")";
        }

        DisplayAlert("", msg, "Ok");
```

Not giving any result on iOS.
what I am missing to detect QR Code by the iOS device.

Comment: Try updating the kernel in IOS.  Often issues like this is due to bugs in the an older version of the kernel.  Do both machines have same version of Core?

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your comment. I am testing it on two devices 1. iPhone XR with the latest iOS version. 2. iPhone 11 Pro MAX also with the latest version.

Comment: I said kernel!!! See : https://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-releases-ios-kernel-source-code/?force_isolation=true